# Syntax error in PL/SQL Oracle script when creating a sequence

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following PL/SQL script which I am trying to execute using the Oracle SQL Developer's "Run Script" command.

```
declare      
  current_max_value_id      number(8, 0);

begin

  select max(id) into current_max_value_id from "DIM_VALUE";

  create sequence value_id_seq 
    increment by 1
    start with current_max_value_id + 1
    nomaxvalue
    nocycle; 

  insert all                
    into "DIM_VALUE" (ID, UNIT_ID) values (value_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 1)
    into "DIM_VALUE" (ID, UNIT_ID) values (value_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 2)
    ...
  select * from dual;

  drop sequence value_id_seq;

end;
```

I get the following error:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" when expecting one of the following:
```

After searching similar issues, I guess this should be somehow resolved putting `/` somewhere, but I have not yet figured out where exactly (and why it is even needed - isn't the script, as written above, unambiguous enough for the interpreter?).

Comment: Dropping and creating objects at runtime in Oracle is a bad plan.  You can't issue DDL from PL/SQL without resorting to dynamic SQL presumably with an `execute immediate`.  But it doesn't make sense to create a sequence just to drop it a moment later.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why isn't there a sequence for `dim_value.id` in the first place?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Let's assume there isn't and I cannot change that. Also, I need to insert tens of rows into the table and the values are logically grouped, so it may happen that someone else will need to modify the script by putting more `INSERT`s somewhere in the middle. For these reasons, I thought using just `value_id_seq.NEXTVAL` would make the maintenance much easier and error-proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use DDL on PL/SQL. You'll need `execute immediate`

```
declare      
  current_max_value_id      number(8, 0);

begin

  select max(id) into current_max_value_id from DIM_VALUE;

  execute immediate 'create sequence value_id_seq increment by 1 start with current_max_value_id + 1 nomaxvalue nocycle'; 

  -- Edited based on Alex's Poole comment
  execute immediate 'insert into DIM_VALUE (ID, UNIT_ID) values (value_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 1)';
  execute immediate 'insert into DIM_VALUE (ID, UNIT_ID) values (value_id_seq.NEXTVAL, 2)';

  execute immediate 'drop sequence value_id_seq';

end;
```

You could also try without sequence with `connect by level` (you'll need to change `someLimit` with the number of records you are looking to create)

```
declare      
  current_max_value_id      number(8, 0);

begin

  select max(id) into current_max_value_id from DIM_VALUE;


  insert into DIM_VALUE (ID, UNIT_ID) 
   select level + nvl(current_max_value_id,0), level
     from dual
   connect by level <= someLimit;

end;
```

Comment: The insert would have to be dynamic too; at compile time the sequence still doesn't exist so `value_id_seq.NEXTVAL` would error. And I believe the `insert all` would get the same sequence value for all the rows anyway, it's only evaluated once. The connect-by approach makes much more sense anyway though, and also doesn't have the implicit commit from the DDL.

Comment: btw I would avoid double-quoting identifiers as a matter of best practice. It may work here but it's asking for trouble.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, you are right, I don't know why OP was using them